# Set Doctrine entity value to NULL?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have googled and all answers seem to suggest using a query builder - but I would prefer to have this value set to NULL via the entity API (ie: setUsername(null)).

Doing this however sets the value as an empty string not a NULL.

Is there any way to achieve this without resorting to implementing an UPDATE  query?

EDIT

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$quote = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Quote')->findOneByUuid($uuid);
if (null !== $quote) {
    $quote->setUuid(null); // *** SET EMPTY STRING NOT RDBMS NULL ***

    $em->persist($quote);
    $em->flush();

    return $this->render('quote/thanks.html.twig');
}
```

ENTITY

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true, length=36, nullable=false)
 */
private $uuid;
```

Comment: What "this value"? This question is unclear at its finest. Add more relevant details.

Comment: In Your database if the default value of the column is set to empty string and you are setting value from doctrine to null, it will set the value to empty string not null

Comment: Show the `username` field definition (with doctrine annotations).

Comment: I am not sure I can make the question any clearer - see the code I added above I guess? I am trying to set a field to NULL (RDBMS NULL) using the entity and em API. This code above is setting the UUID to empty string not NULL

Comment: @WaqarHaider that was it. Thank you :) If you want to post that as the answer I'll accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Your database if the default value of the column is set to empty string and you are setting value from doctrine to null, it will set the value to empty string not null

Answer (score 4):

You should set nullable to `true` on your entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true, length=36, nullable=true)
 */
private $uuid;
```

After that you should run this doctrine command:

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```